# Github Actions - workflow_run three levels of workflows

Tags: github-actions

For example in my repository I have 3 github action workflows

**integration.yml**

```
name: integration

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches: ["develop"]

jobs:
  tests:
    uses: blablablabla............
```

**develop-tagging.yml**

```
name: develop-tagging

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["integration"]
    branches: ["develop"]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
    actions-tagger:
      if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps: blablablabla............
```

**develop-deployment.yml**

```
name: develop-deployment

    on:
      workflow_dispatch:
      workflow_run:
        workflows: ["develop-tagging"]
        branches: ["develop"]
        types:
          - completed
    
    jobs:
      actions-deployment:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps: blablablabla............
```

When i make changes to develop
**Expectation**

> integration --> develop-tagging --> develop-deployment

**Reality**

> integration --> develop-tagging

In the documentation:
You cannot use workflow_run to chain more than three levels of workflows
https://docs.github.com/es/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run

Workflow develop-deployment never runs

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. see api [Create a workflow dispatch event](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event) need `ref` to determine the branch, also you can see that in manual run.
   [image: manual run img]
2. then see the event need file in default branch, and the `GITHUB_REF` is constant, so guess that event trigger the next workflow with the default branch.
   [image]
3. so run a [demo](https://github.com/bxb100/action-test/actions/runs/1682840018), remove `develop-deployment.yml` braches limit, it works.

```
name: develop-deployment
on:
      workflow_dispatch:
      workflow_run:
        workflows: ["develop-tagging"]
        types:
          - completed
    
jobs:
  actions-deployment:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps: 
        - run: echo 'C'
```